# Scrape data by sending payload with an API in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to fetch list of articles from gfg based on a query. We can achieve this by using search box present in this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ .
[image]

[image]

They are using this api to display results "https://api.geeksforgeeks.org/post/api/googlesearch/" and they are passing search query in payload.

[image]

[image]

This is the approach i have tried:

```
import requests
d = {'page':3, 'sort':'relevance', 'type':'premium', 'query':'nump'}
r=requests.get('https://api.geeksforgeeks.org/post/api/googlesearch/',  data = d).json()
print(r)
```

but i am getting this error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Any solution for this problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The api takes a POST request you are sending a GET request try changing to this:

```
import requests
d = {'page':3, 'sort':'relevance', 'type':'premium', 'query':'nump'}
r=requests.post('https://api.geeksforgeeks.org/post/api/googlesearch/',  data = d).json()
print(r)
```